# Instagram API to filter tag based image

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, instagram

I there a ways if can show tag based images along with filter to so that we can control which images to show or not to show.

For example  i want to show only tags that `volkswagen` and i want to show only volkswagen related image not junk is there a way that we can filter and show filter image on the website

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

UPDATE:

Fiddle http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNzGYw

Answer (score 1):

That will be difficult since anybody can use whatever #hashtag..

As a suggestion, you could have a whitelist/blacklist based on the username's. The api gives you the username, so you can filter the results based on that and only show images from verified sources.

Don't know if this is scalable and will solve 100% of the cases, but maybe will fit your project.

Comment: Yes, I thought of it first as the last option practically i am not sure how to  filter image based on tags as anyone can tag image as any tag.